# How to align 2 different tables

Tags: javascript, html

my main table is 2nd table below for the column 5,6 (bug) i need to add a header & 7,8,9 columns another header (not bug).

for the second table i have a sorting function applied so not able to add a new row in a that table header, i need sorting and header to be added [sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfplK.png)

how to create a header with sorting

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="css/sorttable.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <table class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-border w3-hoverable w3-white tabthree">

    <thead>
      <tr class="action-yes">
        <td colspan="5"></td>
        <td colspan="2"><b>Application Issues (bugs)</b></td>
        <td colspan="3"><b>Test issues (Not bugs)</b></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>


  <table class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-border w3-hoverable w3-white sortable">

    <thead>

      <th style="width: 10px;">
        <div align="center" ;>Job</div>
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Success <br />#
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Failed <br />#
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Skipped <br />#
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Total <br />#
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">New <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Known <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Env <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Data <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Test <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;"><br />Comments</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: why are they in separate tables if you want them to be aligned. can you put your two tables in a table?

Comment: 2nd table has sorting capability  https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js , if i merge 2 tables sort to table headers is removed

Comment: what about nesting your Table A and your sortable table both within another table.  ultimately you want them to overlap in that they share a column set.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have 2 separate table, just use one and then the colspan

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-black.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="css/sorttable.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <table class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-border w3-hoverable w3-white tabthree">

    <thead>

      <tr class="action-yes">
        <th colspan="5"></td>
        <th colspan="2"><b>Application Issues (bugs)</b></td>
        <th colspan="3"><b>Test issues (Not bugs)</b></td>
        <th colspan="1"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <th style="width: 10px;">
        <div align="center" ;>Job</div>
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Success <br />#
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Failed <br />#
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Skipped <br />#
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Total <br />#
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">New <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Known <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Env <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Data <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;">Test <br />Issues
      </th>
      <th style="width: 10px;"><br />Comments</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: as mentioned above main table has sorting capability "https://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js", i am using this js to sort the table,, once i add a new row in thead sorting is removed, i need sorting and two headers aligned,